# Outlook Addin Error Code 13005 for auth.getAccessTokenAsync

Tags: single-sign-on, outlook-addin, access-token, office-js, office-addins

So I am trying to use single sign on in an outlook addin. I have registered my app at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/. 
In my Manifest I have

```
<WebApplicationInfo>
            <Id>{myId}</Id>
            <Resource>api://mydomain.com:3000/{myId}</Resource>
            <Scopes>
                <Scope>Mail.Read</Scope>
                <Scope>profile</Scope>
            </Scopes>
        </WebApplicationInfo>
```

mydomain.com is actually a domain i map to my local IP. 
Outlook accepts my manifest just fine. How ever when i call `Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync`, I get the following response

`{name: "Invalid application resource Url provided.", message: "Invalid resource Url specified in the manifest.", code: 13004}`

How else should i write the resource url. Am i supposed to add this url somewhere else?

I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2 and was able to get further. But now i Get `{name: "Preauthorization missing.", message: "Missing grant for this add-in.", code: 13005}`

Comment: This sounds like an issue with consent.

If you are the admin of the tenant you are working with, grant administrator consent to the add-in following the instructions here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/grant-admin-consent-to-an-add-in.

If you are not the admin, force consent in the API call. For how to do that, go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins, and look at the instructions for error code 13007.

Comment: Yes that worked. I intend to use the access token to call the microsoft graph but its not authorized...what am i missing?

Comment: Just to make sure the <resource> url in your example is your actual domain right? and not "mydomain.com" ? (you also need to use the correct domain in the AAD registration and source URL) 

Are you getting an additional error now?

Comment: I see this is started appearing today in our tenant for outlook add-ins. Nothing changed either add-in or the code since 3 months. I am looking all over internet for the solution. error: OSF.DDA.Error
name: "Preauthorization missing."
message: "Missing grant for this add-in."
code: 13005

Comment: Any update on this? I am also getting the same error 13005, even when I am trying with the global admin's outlook account itself. I have provided the admin consent also for all users.  I am following this code to begin with. [link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-SSO)

Comment: I am able to resolve it for my case .Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67095595/error-getting-sso-in-outlook-365-web-addin-13005-preauthorization-missing?noredirect=1#comment118604689_67095595), if this can save time and efforts.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve Error 13005 by adding /taskpane.html to the end of my redirect URI in the authentication tab of my App Registration [Figure 1]. Originally I just had https://loacalhost:3000 as my redirect URI. Just make sure that whatever endpoint the user is being redirected to is the redirect URI. Seems simple but I spent a lot of time on this.

If you can't figure out what your redirect endpoint is, inspect the taskpane element and then look at the top of the tab. It should be something like DevTools - {localhost:3000/taskpane.html}?_... The text inside of the curly braces is the endpoint, make sure that the whole string is added to the Authentication tab in App registrations.

[App Registration Page Example Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1Cmm.png)

I hope this helps,

Lucius

Comment: Hello, I don't understand how you find your endpoint in devtools, could you help?