# getAccessTokenAsync return 13005

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to integrate microsoft graph api into our outlook add-in. I have registered add-in by following below documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2

I have updated add-in manifest and added webapplicationinfo based on below documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins

The problem is happening when I try to get access token for graph api by using below code.

```
Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync(function (result) {
    if (result.status === "succeeded") {
        // Use this token to call Web API
        var ssoToken = result.value;
        ...
    } else {
        if (result.error.code === 13003) {
            // SSO is not supported for domain user accounts, only
            // work or school (Office 365) or Microsoft Account IDs.
        } else {
            // Handle error
        }
    }
});
```

while executing above code, I got screen for granting permission and when I grant all permissions the callback function is getting executed from office.js with failure response.

```
code: 13005
message: "Missing grant for this add-in."
name: "Preauthorization missing."
```

My administrator grant all add-in permission by following below documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/grant-admin-consent-to-an-add-in

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you referenced to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51242859/outlook-addin-error-code-13005-for-auth-getaccesstokenasync)?  It seems it is duplicate.

Comment: This is a similar issue as pointed by Tom. Please follow the link to see if it can resolve your problem.

Comment: This is resolved . Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67095595/error-getting-sso-in-outlook-365-web-addin-13005-preauthorization-missing?noredirect=1#comment118604689_67095595)