# Error getting SSO in Outlook 365 web addin 13005. Preauthorization missing

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on, azure-ad-graph-api, outlook-web-addins

I am working upon an outlook add-in and I am trying to get SSO token to call Graph API. I am referring this link to develop my addin [Outlook addin SSO](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-SSO).
I registered my App in Azure AD (multi-tenant).
and followed everything step by step

I added version override to  Manifest

```
  <Id>Client_id-xxx-xxx</Id>
  <Resource>api://localhost:44361/Client_id-xxx-xxx</Resource>
  <Scopes>
    <Scope>openid</Scope>
    <Scope>offline_access</Scope>
    <Scope>profile</Scope>
    <Scope>Files.ReadWrite</Scope>
    <Scope>Mail.Read</Scope>
    <Scope>User.Read</Scope>
    <Scope>email</Scope>
  </Scopes>
</WebApplicationInfo>
```

authconfig.js

```
var authConfig = {
    
    clientId:"Client_id-xxx-xxx",
    scopes: "Files.ReadWrite Mail.Read openid offline_access profile email User.Read",
    redirectUrl: "https://localhost:44361/MessageRead.html"
};
```

Web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ida:AppId" value="Client_Id_xx-xx" />
    <add key="ida:Audience" value="Client_id_xx_xx" />
    <add key="ida:AppPassword" value="app_Password" />
    <add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44361/MessageRead.html" />
    <add key="ida:Authority" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0" />
  </appSettings>
```

I have granted the admin consent to all users in the tenant as well. (see attachment)
[image: admin consent granted]

My javascript code :

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
     //   console.log("In Office.initialize ", reason);
        $(document).ready(function () {
       //     console.log("In Office.ready ");
            if (OfficeHelpers.Authenticator.isAuthDialog()) return;
            var element = document.querySelector('.ms-MessageBanner');
            messageBanner = new fabric.MessageBanner(element);
            messageBanner.hideBanner();

            authenticator = new OfficeHelpers.Authenticator();
            authenticator.endpoints.registerMicrosoftAuth(authConfig.clientId, {
                redirectUrl: authConfig.redirectUrl,
                scope: authConfig.scopes
            });

            //loadProps();

        });
    };

    function GetSSOToken(DataObj) {
            var attachmentIds = getAttechamentIdList();
            //if (Office.context.auth !== undefined && Office.context.auth.getAccessToken !== undefined) {
            if (OfficeRuntime.auth !== undefined && OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken !== undefined) {
            
                OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken().then(function (result) {
                    if (result.status === "succeeded") {
                       
                        // No need to prompt user, use this token to call Web API 
                        saveEmailWithSSO(result.value, attachmentIds, DataObj);
                    } else if (result.error.code == 13007 || result.error.code == 13005) {
                        console.log('error:', result.error.code);
                        // These error codes indicate that we need to prompt for consent
                        // Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync({ forceConsent: true }, function (result) {
                        
                        OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken({ allowConsentPrompt: true, allowSignInPrompt: true }, function (result) {
                            if (result.status === "succeeded") {
                                console.log('AccessToken:', result.value);
                                saveEmailWithSSO(result.value, attachmentIds, DataObj);
                            } else {
                                // Could not get SSO token, proceed with authentication prompt
                                console.log('in with prompt else1 ');
                                // console.log('error:', result.error.code);
    
                                saveEmailWithPrompt(attachmentIds);
    
                               
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        // Could not get SSO token, proceed with authentication prompt
                      
                        console.log('in with prompt else2 ');
                        console.log('error:', result.error.code);
                        saveEmailWithPrompt(attachmentIds);
    
                    }
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log('in catch', error);  
                });
            }
```

the above code is always ending up in Catch block with error 13005, Missing Preauthorization, Missing grant for this addin.

I have referred and made changes from this link also https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/923
even the similar questions here could not resolve it. Please suggest what else could be done to resolve.

I am trying to run this code with a global admin's outlook account and another user from outside tenant. but not working in both the cases.

------update----

After some work around I am able to see this issue in sign in (while using forceConsent allowConsentPrompt) [image: AADSTS90008]I can see this error

Comment: What is the Outlook client you are seeing this on (Outlook Desktop, online, mac, etc) and what is the client version? Have you taken a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins?  For user outside the tenant, could you check that you have consented to the app?  The information is under "Provide user consent to the app" in the link you noted (https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-SSO#provide-user-consent-to-the-app)

Comment: I am using office 365 outlook on the web. I have updated my question as I could see another error screen. Please suggest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved ! After hours of brainstorming , I am able to resolve this error by revisting the document again.
I overlooked step 12 of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2[image]